# decompress a bz2 file from BytesIO

Tags: python, csv, paramiko

I want to read a bz2 file in a server, decompress it and read with csv parser, but I still have the error;

```
    myfile = bz2.BZ2File(bio.read(), "rb")
TypeError: file() argument 1 must be encoded string without NULL bytes, not str

import paramiko
from config import config
import bz2
import csv
import StringIO
from io import BytesIO
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect(config.get('mrc_ssh', 'host'), username=config.get('mrc_ssh', 'user'))
sftp_client = ssh.open_sftp()
_file = sftp_client.open('/home/myfile.bz2')
bio = BytesIO(_file.read())
print bio
myfile = bz2.BZ2File(bio.read(), "rb")
reader = csv.DictReader(myfile)
for row in reader:
    print row
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`bz2.BZ2File`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/bz2.html#bz2.BZ2File) takes a *filename* as the first argument. Not actual data.

Either use (if you can store locally the file):

```
myfile = bz2.BZ2File('/home/myfile.bz2', "rb")
```

Or use the one-shot decompression function [`bz2.decompress`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/bz2.html#bz2.decompress)

```
uncompressed_data = bz2.decompress(bio.read())
```

Comment: @nam In addition, I don't think you need the extra step of using a BytesIO here. But that is an other story ;)